# prevent default not stopping page refresh. Passing form information to and from php with ajax in a wordpress site

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, forms

I have seen a number of methods dating back to about 2011 in order to take a form and have its data posted via ajax.jquery. I have tried a couple and am just getting the page to reload despite using `preventdefault functions`.

I am trying to take data from my form, have the jQuery listen for the form submit by targeting the actual form id and then call a PHP function in order to have that data posted to the db. Ultimately nothing happens other than a page reload. Since this is a WP page, I know that some of the functions and handling differ from regular webpages. Things like the ajax url, can be passed back to the functions etc. That is why I Am posting this here.

the form:

```
function add_entry(){
    ?>
    <form action="" method="post" id="ajax-add-to-form" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="text" id="FName" name="FName" placeholder="First Name" value="" required>
        <input type="text" id="LName" name="LName" placeholder="Last Name" value="" required>
        <select id="size" required>
            <option value="">Size</option>
            <?php  for($i=1; $i<=15; $i++){?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="MobileNumber" name="MobileNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" value="" required>
        <input type="email" id="Customer_Email" name="Customer_Email" placeholder="Email Address" value="" required>
        <input type="submit"  name="ajax-add-to-form" value="Add to">
<?php
    
    }
add_shortcode('add_entry', 'add_entry');


</form>
```

**the jquery**

```
jQuery('document').ready( function(){
jQuery('#ajax-add-to-form').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault(); 
jQuery('#jx-loading').show();
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
    data: { 
    action: 'ajax-php-function'},
    success: function(data)
    {jQuery('#jx-loading').hide();}
})          
}); 
return false;       
});
```

**the php**

```
function ajax-php-function() {          
    global $wpdb;   
    $table = "mytablename";     
    $FName= $_POST['FName'];    
    $LName= $_POST['LName'];    
    $MobileNumber= $_POST['MobileNumber'];  
    $Email = $_POST['Email '];          
    $data = array(
    'FName' => $FName,
    'LName' => $LName,      
    'MobileNumber' => $MobileNumber,        
    'Email' => $Email);     
    $success = $wpdb->insert( $table, $data );          
    if($success)
    {echo json_encode($last_data);} 
    else{       echo 'error';   }   die;            
}
```

Comment: Hi, Theodoro, welcome to WPSE. Before going deeper in a answer, I would suggest to put `e.preventDefault();` before anything else on the `jQuery('#ajax-add-to-form').on('submit', function(e){` function. Let me know if works.

Comment: @celsobessa thanks. Sorry I have updated the code above since I had already tried that but forgot to update here. It didnt make a difference which is why I am so lost

Comment: Also, simplify your debugging by commenting out parts so that you can confirm each part as working one at a time - then try the entire process once each is happy.

Comment: You mean function(e){e.preventDefault() - right?

Comment: sorry yes someone else told me to try event there at the same time I was typing this. Didnt work

Comment: Then the issue is not here - put in more debugging ( try to console.log inside your event listener to check it is being run ) - find any other listeners attached to submit events etc.. we can't help much if the issue is not in the code you share.

Comment: Thats all the code there is for this one:/ Because its wordpress I get almost nothing useful in the console I can see. Here is the Network tab and all I can get https://snipboard.io/EypHhi.jpg

Comment: `#ajax-add-to-form` targets the ID of the form itself, instead try targeting the input that has `name="ajax-add-to-form"`.  Change your javascript to `$( input[name="ajax-add-to-form"] ).on( 'click', function(e) {`.
That should address your `preventDefault()` issue - after that I don't know if the rest will work, but it looks pretty sound.  Sometimes writing to custom tables can be fickle though and there could be a myriad of different conflicts and such but I can't debug that from here. Look at this for errors using WPDB: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/179074/60844

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the form and its old handler were being trashed by some other element in the website. Could have been WP or one of the few plug ins I could not remove as it is the page builder (Elementor, Elementor Essentials). After disabling all the other plug ins it is narrowed down to that. The code solution was:
....

```
jQuery(document).on('submit', '#ajax-add-to-waitlist-form', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
```

.......

Instead of

```
jQuery('#ajax-add-to-form').on('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
```